# How to extract text from Field using lxml, if field exists?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm pretty new to lxml and I have an xml file containing 40,000 rows of data. I have read the tutorial for lxml but I'm uncertain which of the buildin functions is suited best to achieve my goal, which is to extract the text from a certain element, dependend on the elements existence. 
The xml file is structured as follows:

```
    <main>
      <header>
        <row type="info">
          <field name="description"><![CDATA[Results]]></field>
          <field name="created"><![CDATA[6/12/2014 6:45:00 PM]]></field>
        </row>
        <row>
          <field name="profile"><![CDATA[Intel]]></field>
        </row>
      </header>
      <sections>
        <section name="Results">
          <description />
          <parameters />
          <header />
          <content>
            <row>
              # A row-dependend number of fields exist before the Full Content field
              <field name="Full Content"><![CDATA[ I am the text of interest]]></field>
              # A row-dependend number of fields follow here
            </row>
            # There are 40,000 of these row elements
          </content>
          <footer>
            <row type="content_count">
              <field name="count"><![CDATA[9981]]></field>
            </row>
          </footer>
        </section>
      </sections>
    </main>
```

I'm looking to extract the text from the fields in each of the 40,000 rows and store the data in a dictionary.

I'm not sure how to traverse the xml tree using the field names (which seems to be the way to go since the index of the subelements change from row to row.

Currently, I have a number of these xml files stored in a list that I created as follows:

```
files = get_files("P:\\Data\\files")
xmls = []
for file in files:
    parser = etree.XMLParser(ns_clean=True, recover = True)
    tree = etree.parse(file, parser=parser)
    root = tree.getroot()
    xmls.append(root)
```

Thank you for any advice
Matthias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example how to use `lxml.cssselect()`

```
import lxml
import lxml.html

data = '''    <main>
      <header>
        <row type="info">
          <field name="description"><![CDATA[Results]]></field>
          <field name="created"><![CDATA[6/12/2014 6:45:00 PM]]></field>
        </row>
        <row>
          <field name="profile"><![CDATA[Intel]]></field>
        </row>
      </header>
      <sections>
        <section name="Results">
          <description />
          <parameters />
          <header />
          <content>
            <row>
              # A row-dependend number of fields exist before the Full Content field
              <field name="Full Content"><![CDATA[ I am the text of interest]]></field>
              # A row-dependend number of fields follow here
            </row>
            # There are 40,000 of these row elements
          </content>
          <footer>
            <row type="content_count">
              <field name="count"><![CDATA[9981]]></field>
            </row>
          </footer>
        </section>
      </sections>
    </main>'''

html = lxml.html.fromstring(data)

fields = html.cssselect('field')

for x in fields:
     print lxml.etree.tostring(x)
```

.

```
<field name="description"/>

<field name="created"/>

<field name="profile"/>

<field name="Full Content"/>
              # A row-dependend number of fields follow here

<field name="count"/>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version to get text in DATA[]

```
import lxml
import lxml.etree

data = '''  ... html_as_previouse  ... '''

et = lxml.etree.fromstring(data)

fields = et.xpath('//field')

for x in fields:
    print x.text
```

.

```
Results
6/12/2014 6:45:00 PM
Intel
 I am the text of interest
9981
```

---

**EDIT:**

Finding fields by name

```
named_fields = et.xpath('//field[@name="count"]')

for x in named_fields:
    print x.text
```

Comment: How does this actually extract the content of the field, eg. the "I am the text of interest" part?

Comment: Works like a charm! However, as far as I can see, it does not allow the extraction of a particular field based on its name, eg. "Full Content". Due to the fact that the amount of fields prior to the field might change, accessing it by index doesn't seem to do the trick.

I will accept this answer though, since it does solve the question. 
I'll make another question that states the particular problem of acesssing the "<field name="Name">" type fields more clearly.